# Count the number of occurences of a certain value for each column and display it in a graph in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am a recently hired Data Analyst for a company and I'm building a dashboard for a scorecard and I want it to display each question occurences of "Non compliant" responses. My database is structured somewhat like this:

| Score ID | Question 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | Compliant |
| 5678 | Non compliant |

And so forth. The score IDs are connected to a database of agents and their final scores for each ID. My final objective is being able to visualize the totals of non compliant items and filter it to my needs (time analysis, group analysis etc). How do I perform this in Power BI? I figured this would be a very easy in Excel, but I'm struggling a lot to have this done in Power BI

I've attempted unpivoting the columns, creating a column graph by just dragging all the fields and counting the number of occurrnces in Excel, but the latter onyl gives me a static number.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create measures for this. Try the following:

```
Count Compliant =
  CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('YourTable'[Score ID]),
    'YourTable'[Question 1] = "Compliant"
  )


Count Non compliant =
  CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('YourTable'[Score ID]),
    'YourTable'[Question 1] = "Non compliant"
  )
```

And if you do unpivot your table (you should) then:

```
Count Question Compliant =
  CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('YourTable'[Question ID]),
    'YourTable'[Question Value] = "Compliant"
  )


Count Question Non compliant =
  CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('YourTable'[Question ID]),
    'YourTable'[Question Value] = "Non compliant"
  )
```

These measures will serve as the base for your other measures.

Comment: So I'll have to do this calculation for each question? This is what I was trying to avoid, because each questionnaire has over 50 questions

Comment: Which is why you need to unpivot your data and use the second set of measures (you'll need to modify the column names accordingly).

Comment: I've attempted unpivoting the data and it didn't work

Comment: What didn't work? What does your table look like? Update your question above so we can see how question 2, 3 ... are structured in your table.